# Environment on google Appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

does someone have an idea how to get the environment variables on Google-AppEngine ?

I'm trying to write a simple Script that shall use the Client-IP (for Authentication) and a parameter (geturl or so) from the URL (for e.g. `http://thingy.appspot.dom/index?geturl=www.google.at`)

I red that i should be able to get the Client-IP via "request.remote_addr" but i seem to lack 'request' even tho i imported webapp from google.appengine.ext

Many thanks in advance,
 Birt

Comment: Can you post some of the code you have in main.py (assuming that is where you try to get the request parameters)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, assuming you're using webapp: you can get the client ip address via self.request.remote_addr and the parameter with self.request.get("geturl")

See the [Handling Forms with webapp](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/handlingforms.html) section of the tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the actual question from the title of your post, assuming you're still wondering: to get environment variables, simple `import os` and the environment is available in `os.environ`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using webapp or doing CGI-style? The webapp request class is documented at [the appengine docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass.html).